# Programs with Javascript json parsing

Tags: javascript, titanium

I am trying to parse a json object and try to do an alert in js if a particular word is detected in the json string,

```
CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function (evt) {
//alert(evt);
    alert(evt.payload);
    var jsonNotification = JSON.parse(evt.payload);
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonNotification.length; i++) {
                var text = new String(jsonNotification[i]);
                if (text ==  'Hello') {
                    alert('Hello');
                }else{
                    alert('Error');
                }
    }
```

I am however getting some errors that the alert 'Hello' does not display. Not really sure if I am doing it correctly. Hopefully someone can shed some light.

Comment: What is your JSON input? You realise that this will alert "error" once per attribute which is *not* "Hello", yes? Also you don't need the new String bit; just set `text` to `jsonNotification[i]` directly.

Comment: What data do you expect from `evt.payload`?

Answer (score 0):

```
CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', 
    function (evt) {

        // parse the desired data  
        var data= JSON.parse(evt.payload),
            key;

        // loop over all the keys of the JSON object
        for (key in data) {
            if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                alert( data[key] ===  'Hello' ? 'Hello' : 'Error' );
            }
    }
);
```

Comment: In this user's example, it looks like he is using an array (If he is not, then that's the problem with the code). You should not use `for..in` to loop through arrays, as it is rather slow and will not be in the right order, instead the `i < whatever.length` method is preferred.